# Is it enough to install SP3 of SQL Server 2005 alone?

Tags: sql-server-2005, service-pack

I installed SQL Server 2005, and I want to install service packs, I have service packs 1, 2, 3, but I want to know, Is it different to install just service pack 3? or I should install first SP1, the SP2 and finally SP3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just install service pack 3.

The download page for [SQL Server 2005 SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4&displaylang=en) states:

> SQL Server 2005 service packs are
>   cumulative, and this service pack
>   upgrades all service levels of SQL
>   Server 2005 to SP3.